# Mocking FacesContext

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, groovy, mocking, facescontext

I am trying to add some unit tests to a JSF application. This application didnt rely heavily on any best practices, so many service methods use the `FacesContext` to pull data from managed session beans like so:

(this is inside a util class)

```
  public static Object getPageBean(String beanReference) {
      FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
      VariableResolver vr = fc.getApplication().getVariableResolver();
      return vr.resolveVariable(fc, beanReference);
  }
```

What would be the best way to mock this? I am using groovy so i have a few more options for creating classes that i cant normally create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in my case i was able to mock it in pure groovy.
i provide a map of MockBeans that it can return:

```
private FacesContext getMockFacesContext(def map){
        def fc = [
          "getApplication": {
            return ["getVariableResolver": {
              return ["resolveVariable": { FacesContext fc, String name ->
                return map[name]
              }] as VariableResolver
            }] as Application
          },
          "addMessage": {String key, FacesMessage val ->
            println "added key: [${key}] value: [${val.getDetail()}] to JsfContext messages"
          },
          "getMessages": {return null}
        ] as FacesContext;
        return fc;
      }
```

Comment: Interesting. I might need to take a closer look to Groovy.

Comment: the only problem with this approach is that i need to add all the methods i want to use to the mock object

Answer (score 18):

You can return a mock context via `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance` by invoking [`setCurrentInstance(FacesContext)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#setCurrentInstance%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) before running the test. The method is protected, but you can access it either via reflection or by extending `FacesContext`. There is a sample implementation using Mockito [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/12/jsf-mocking-facescontext-for-unit-tests.html#mockFacesCurrentInstance).

Answer (score 13):

This url provides a really good article on it: 
http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/12/jsf-mocking-facescontext-for-unit-tests.html

You have your managed bean:

```
 package foo;

import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class AlphaBean {
  public String incrementFoo() {
    Map<String, Object> session = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext()
        .getSessionMap();
    Integer foo = (Integer) session.get("foo");
    foo = (foo == null) ? 1 : foo + 1;
    session.put("foo", foo);
    return null;
  }
}
```

You stub out the FacesContext:

```
package foo.test;

import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;

public abstract class ContextMocker extends FacesContext {
  private ContextMocker() {
  }

  private static final Release RELEASE = new Release();

  private static class Release implements Answer<Void> {
    @Override
    public Void answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
      setCurrentInstance(null);
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static FacesContext mockFacesContext() {
    FacesContext context = Mockito.mock(FacesContext.class);
    setCurrentInstance(context);
    Mockito.doAnswer(RELEASE)
        .when(context)
        .release();
    return context;
  }
}
```

Then write your unit test:

```
@Test
  public void testIncrementFoo() {
    FacesContext context = ContextMocker.mockFacesContext();
    try {
      Map<String, Object> session = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      ExternalContext ext = mock(ExternalContext.class);
      when(ext.getSessionMap()).thenReturn(session);
      when(context.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(ext);

      AlphaBean bean = new AlphaBean();
      bean.incrementFoo();
      assertEquals(1, session.get("foo"));
      bean.incrementFoo();
      assertEquals(2, session.get("foo"));
    } finally {
      context.release();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use for example **PowerMock** which is a framework that allows you to extend mock libraries like **Mockito** with extra capabilities. In this case it allows you to mock the static methods of `FacesContext`.

If you are using Maven, use following [link](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Mockito_maven) to check the needed dependency setup.

Annotate your JUnit test class using these two annotations. The first annotation tells JUnit to run the test using `PowerMockRunner`. The second annotation tells **PowerMock** to prepare to mock the `FacesContext` class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FacesContext.class })
public class PageBeanTest {
```

Mock `FacesContext` using **PowerMock** and use `verify()` of **Mockito** in order to check that `resolveVariable()` was called with the expected parameters.

```
@Test
public void testGetPageBean() {
    // mock all static methods of FacesContext
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);

    FacesContext facesContext = mock(FacesContext.class);
    when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(facesContext);

    Application application = mock(Application.class);
    when(facesContext.getApplication()).thenReturn(application);

    VariableResolver variableResolver = mock(VariableResolver.class);
    when(application.getVariableResolver()).thenReturn(variableResolver);

    PageBean.getPageBean("bean_reference");

    verify(variableResolver)
            .resolveVariable(facesContext, "bean_reference");
}
```

I've created a [blog post](https://www.codenotfound.com/2014/11/mockito-unit-testing-facescontext-powermock-junit.html) which explains the above code sample in more detail.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to use Mockito and reflection to mock FacesContext and to make sure normal calls to FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() returns the (mocked) instance you want:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {

    // Use Mockito to make our Mocked FacesContext look more like a real one
    // while making it returns other Mocked objects
    ExternalContext externalContext = Mockito.mock(ExternalContext.class);
    Flash flash = Mockito.mock(Flash.class);
    FacesContext facesContext = Mockito.mock(FacesContext.class);
    Mockito.when(facesContext.getExternalContext()).thenReturn(externalContext);
    Mockito.when(externalContext.getFlash()).thenReturn(flash);

    // Use Java reflection to set the FacesContext to our Mock, since
    // FacesContext.setCurrentInstance() is protected.
    try {
        Method setter = FacesContext.class.getDeclaredMethod("setCurrentInstance", new Class[]{FacesContext.class});
        setter.setAccessible(true);
        setter.invoke(null, new Object[]{facesContext});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception in reflection-based access to FacesContext");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

(This is adapted / extended from @McDowell's answer below.)

Answer (score 3):

I give you an example to mock FacesConext without using PowerMockito. The idea is to extend a simple class from Facescontext, and change the current instance using protected static method setCurrentInstance:

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext;

public class DummyTest {

    @Mock
    private FacesContext context;

    @Before
    public void before(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ServletContext sc = mock(ServletContext.class);
        new FakeContext(sc);
        assertEquals(context, FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    }

    @Test
    public void dummy(){

    }

    private class FakeContext extends InitFacesContext{

        public FakeContext(ServletContext sc) {
            super(sc);
            setCurrentInstance(context);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is not presented here. Here we go

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FacesContext.class})
public class MyTestClass{

@Mock
private FacesContext facesContext;

@Before
public void init() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);
        PowerMockito.when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(facesContext);
}
```

And you need to import all the PowerMockito bundle in your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>${powermock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```