# Mock FacesContext to test my faces message displayer class

Tags: maven, jsf, junit, mockito, facescontext

My Backing bean:

```java
@ManagedBean(name = "messageDisplayer")
@ViewScoped
public class MessageDisplayer implements Serializable
{
    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    public void showMessage (FacesMessage.Severity severity, String summary, String detail)
    {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        LOGGER.debug("Showing message with severity='{}', summary='{}', detail='{}'", severity, summary, detail);
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(severity, summary, detail));
    }
}
```

Any help on how I can use Mockito to test this class!?

Comment: Check this http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/jsf-mocking-facescontext-for-unit-ests.html#mockFacesCurrentInstance or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252353/mocking-facescontext

Answer (score 2):

Use **PowerMock** to extend **Mockito** so you are able to mock the static methods of `FacesContext`.

If you are using Maven, use following [link](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/Mockito_maven) to check the needed dependency setup.

Annotate your JUnit test class using these two annotations. The first annotation tells JUnit to run the test using `PowerMockRunner`. The second annotation tells **PowerMock** to prepare to mock the `FacesContext` class.

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ FacesContext.class })
public class PageBeanTest {
```

Mock `FacesContext` using **PowerMock**. Use the **Mockito** `verify()` method to make sure the `addMessage()` method was called. Use an `ArgumentCaptor` in order to retrieve the `FacesMessage` that was passed to the `addMessage()` method call on the `FacesContext`. Then run `assertEquals()` to check if the correct values where set to the `FacesMessage`.

```java
@Test
public void test() {
    // mock all static methods of FacesContext
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(FacesContext.class);

    FacesContext facesContext = mock(FacesContext.class);
    when(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).thenReturn(facesContext);

    MessageDisplayer messageDisplayer = new MessageDisplayer();
    messageDisplayer.showMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "summary", "detail");

    // create an ArgumentCaptor for the FacesMessage that will be added to
    // the FacesContext
    ArgumentCaptor<FacesMessage> facesMessageCaptor = ArgumentCaptor
            .forClass(FacesMessage.class);
    // verify if the call to addMessage() was made and capture the
    // FacesMessage that was passed
    verify(facesContext).addMessage(Mockito.anyString(),
            facesMessageCaptor.capture());

    // get the captured FacesMessage and check the set values
    FacesMessage message = facesMessageCaptor.getValue();
    assertEquals(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, message.getSeverity());
    assertEquals("summary", message.getSummary());
    assertEquals("detail", message.getDetail());
}
```

I've created a [blog post](https://www.codenotfound.com/2014/11/mockito-unit-testing-facescontext-powermock-junit.html) which explains the above code sample in more detail.

Comment: Nice post and blog article, +1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use PowerMock to mock static methods.
Here is an example of how to use it: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic